# Excel2007 Pivot Table: Get Percentage with respect to number of different values in a field

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table, worksheet-function

I have a pivot table based on the answers of N persons to M different questions.

Simple Example (in reality their might be more categories for answering than "yes" and "no" and there might also be empty fields with missing answers):

[image]

What I'd like to achieve:

- I'd like to get the results (number of elements in the different groups) in percent with respect to the number of all people. So in this example I'd like to divide the counts in the pivot table by 10 (number of all people which participated).

I know how to calculate the percentage for a row, but this is not what I want.
Is there a way to calculate the percentage as I'd like to have it (maybe with a user defined formula?)?

I could make the count value of all people (10 in the example) available in a separate cell and then divide all count values by the value of that cell, but I did not find a way to do it in the Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your Count of Answer values and select Summarize Data by, then select More Options. Click on the Show values as tab, and then from the drop down box select % of row.
This will show how the values relate to the groups in the rows.

Pictures to help:

[image]
[image]
[image]